# update data in table does not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have joined the insert different data in table A and update different data in table. The insert query is working but the update query does not working. This is the codes:

```
<?php

@session_start();
include "supsrwk_epenyenggaraan.php";
$jenis_kerja = @$_POST['jenis_kerja'];
$No_Rumah = @$_POST['No_Rumah'];
$blok = @$_POST['blok'];
$kelas = @$_POST['kelas'];
$kuarter = @$_POST['kuarter'];
$kawasan = @$_POST['kawasan'];
$pecahan_Kerja = @$_POST['pecahan_Kerja'];
$kos_Kerja = @$_POST['kos_Kerja'];
$jumlah_Kerja = @$_POST['jumlah_Kerja'];
$tarikh = @$_POST['tarikh'];
$success   = "Pendaftaran Berjaya";

$sqlInsert = " INSERT INTO kerja ( jenis_kerja, No_Rumah, blok, kelas, kuarter, kawasan, pecahan_Kerja, kos_Kerja, jumlah_Kerja, tarikh) VALUES ('$jenis_kerja','$No_Rumah','$blok','$kelas','$kuarter','$kawasan','$pecahan_Kerja','$kos_Kerja','$jumlah_Kerja','$tarikh') ";

$updateSQL = "UPDATE aduan SET statusAduan=%s";

$result = mysql_query($sqlInsert , $updateSQL);


if (!$result) {
    die ("Cannot Execute Query".mysql_error());
}else{
    #code...
}
```

Help me?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: change the %s in the update query to a string

Comment: Well, `%s` in `... SET statusAduan=%s` is a string literal. If that is the exact value you want, it needs to be in quotes -> `... SET statusAduan=‘%s‘`. Or you are missing a `sprintf()`.

Comment: i have edited the code..please help me.its not working too @Sean

Comment: Where is the connection string in this line`$result = mysql_query($sqlInsert , $updateSQL);` like this
`mysql_query($updateSQL, $connection)`
I recommend you to use `mysqli_query($conn,$query)` instead because `mysql_query()` is deprecated.